# Jenkins: how to setup Multiple SCM and Pass-through Git commit together?

Tags: git, jenkins

Let say I have an upstream job *U* and a downstream job *D*.

Job *U* as one of the build steps triggers job *D* with **Pass-through Git commit that was built** ticked.

Job *D* has **Mutiple SCM** configured with two Git repos *R1* and *R2*. *R1* is actual project to be built while *R2* is just additional tool repo used in the process of building.

Job *D* configured like that works well if triggered manually. Although when triggered by job *U* with a `GIT_COMMIT` passed, it fails on a checkout from the repo *R2*.

Well, this is not a surprise that hash related to the passed `GIT_COMMIT` exists only in one of the repos as these are completely separate codebases.

I would like to have only *R1* being checkout based on the passed git hash while *R2* should always fetch from `master` branch.

Is there a way to configure it like that anyhow?